# GRANT SELECT does not work for a sequence

Tags: oracle

I have created `xyz` sequence under owner account and granted select privilege for 'abc' Database user but, when I tried to select sequence it says sequence does not exists using abc user.

Owner account

```
CREATE SEQUENCE XYZ MINVALUE 0 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

GRANT SELECT ON XYZ TO ABC;
```

ABC account

```
select XYZ.nextval from dual;
```

I should access `XYZ.nextval` using ABC account. Any help on this is so much appreciated on how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're missing the sequence owner name.

An example (that actually *works*).

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> grant select on seq to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> select scott.seq.nextval from dual;      --> owner.sequence name.nextval

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL>
```

A synonym:

```
SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> create synonym seq for scott.seq;

Synonym created.

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL>
```

A public synonym:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create public synonym seq for seq;

Synonym created.

SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: The example which you gave is working fine. Thank you. But, you have accessed using owner. sequence. Is there any way where we can access without owner. For tables I am able to select without owner.

Comment: You're welcome. Option you're looking for is called a *synonym*. I edited my message by adding some more code; have a look, please.

Comment: This might be a silly question. It says 'cannot create a synonym with same name as object.' otherwise I need to modify my java code a lot

Comment: You have to be connected as "another user", not as the sequence owner (as the *owner* can't have two objects with the same name). The above example creates a private synonym (private to the user who created it). Alternatively, the owner can create a public synonym which can then be used by anyone. Have a look, a new edit.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other suggestions on how to achieve this. I have only two user accounts.

Comment: Well, this *is* the most obvious way to do what you want to do. Anything other would probably be a worse solution than (private or public) synonym.

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestion. I will implement it.

Comment: @Kiran `alter session set current_schema = hr;` This sets the default schema for name resolution.